# Port forwarding is messed up

Tags: ip, port-forwarding, port, ip-camera

recently changed Hikvision Cube IP camera's (DS-2CD2412F) port and then after it does not work. I also changed the port forwarding in the router. It works only for 1 to 2 hrs, then it cannot be accessed from LAN or WAN. I have the same problem with default port 80 now. 
ports are 80, 554, 8000.
All other port forwarding for other device in router works good.
I tried too many ports.
I also changed and tried firmware versions 5.1, 5.2  and 5.3 of the IP camera. but no luck.

It works only (with any http port) for 1 to 2 hrs. after resetting the camera to its factory settings.
After resetting port shows open status, but after 1 hr. something it's closed.
If I use same port with my other device, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, unless you phrased it incorrectly, it is pretty easy to summize the problem here...

> It works only for 1 to 2 hrs, then **it cannot be accessed from LAN** or
>   WAN.

If you cannot access it from the LAN, this is not a router or port forwarding issue, but a camera issue. You verified this yourself...

> If I use same port with my other device, it works fine.

The answer to your problem, not your direct question though, is your camera is defective or there is some other issue with it or it's connectivity. You did all the proper troublshooting, just came to the wrong conclusion. My guess is replacing the camera will correct the problem.